# How to add a checkbox to each meeting in Outlook calendar view to enable/disable a reminder?

Tags: vba, checkbox, outlook

I'd like to be able to click a check box on each of my Outlook Calendar Meeting Invites that would disable the "Reminder" if unchecked (a.k.a. set the Reminder value = None).

Example of Photoshop mock up:

[image: Photoshop mock up]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to customize the current view of the Explorer/Folder objects. The [Currentview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864212.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the Folder or Explorer class returns a View object representing the current view. To obtain a View object for the view of the current Explorer, use Explorer.CurrentView instead of the CurrentView property of the current Folder object returned by Explorer.CurrentFolder.

The View object allows you to create customizable views that allow you to better sort, group and ultimately view data of all different types. There are a variety of different view types that provide the flexibility needed to create and maintain your important data.

- The table view type (olTableView) allows you to view data in a simple field-based table.
- The Calendar view type (olCalendarView) allows you to view data in a calendar format.
- The card view type (olCardView) allows you to view data in a series of cards. Each card displays the information contained by the item and can be sorted.
- The icon view type (olIconView) allows you to view data as icons, similar to a Windows folder or explorer.
- The timeline view type (olTimelineView) allows you to view data as it is received in a customizable linear time line.

Views are defined and customized using the View object's [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868419.aspx) property. The XML property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.

The XML definition describes the view type by using a series of tags and keywords corresponding to various properties of the view itself. When the view is created, the XML definition is parsed to render the settings for the new view.
To determine how the XML should be structured when creating views, you can create a view by using the Outlook user interface and then you can retrieve the XML property for that view.

To programmatically add a custom field to a view, use the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860939.aspx) method of the ViewFields object. This is the recommended way to dynamically change the view over setting the XML property of the View object.

Note, if you are adding a custom property to the ViewFields collection, the property must exist in the UserDefinedProperties collection for the View’s parent folder.